# Internet connection lost for browser but still there for transmission

Tags: internet, internet-connection

I brought Dell Inspiron N5050 few months back. from day 1 i am getting problem with wired connection, i am able to use web browser for few minutes then all of the sudden i lost internet connection but i don't know why transmission is still able to download torrent from internet. today i installed steadyflow download manager and i see it is also downloading fine but beside these everything fails to connect to internet.

> one more thing internet connection is recovered automatically after few minutes. But this problem occurred repeatedly
>
> I have **reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 three times**, but problem is still there

Comment: using any proxy? Try changing dns server to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: no, i don't use any proxy

Comment: Guessing from the other answers it sounds like a problem with DNS. Could you try `nslookup example.com` when your network doesn't work. If you get a timeout this is probably a problem with the DNS server.

Comment: I have changed the DNS server to Google's public DNS 8.8.8.8 as suggested by Web-E. Lets see how it works

Answer (score 0):

From what you say it seems there might be a problem with the DNS servers.

Transmission continues to work because once it got the address (through DNS) it won't need the DNS servers again and DNS works for a few minutes which is enough.

So:

Right-click the network icon and select **Connection information** and take note of the IP addresses of the DNS servers.

Then wait until the browser doesn't work anymore, open a terminal and `ping 10.10.10.10`. Change the address with the one of your DNS servers.

This won't solve your problem but should confirm it is a DNS issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but internet connection is lost for chromium, google chrome,midori apt-get and almost for all apps except Transmission and steadyflow

Comment: and i have reinstalled ubuntu after formatting the / and /home drive

Comment: try another browser (Chromium) for all it's worth.

Comment: dear, i have mentioned in earlier comment this won't work on Chromium, google chrome, Midori

Answer (score 0):

1. Is transmission running in background & downloading some files from torrent? If yes check your network speed (specially if you are using broad-band modem or so). This is not connection speed (it might be always 100/1000MBPS); but your ISP speed. On unlimited plans of some ISP the network speed is limited to upper limits (512kbps, 1mbps..)
2. When connection is lost does it means network connection or browser connection? If network connection then the modem or the cable might be the culprit else only browser then check connection settings of running browser. "No proxy" if you are on broadband modem.

Comment: 1) Transmission is downloading files from internet. 2) connection of browser and any other application using internet except transmission and steadyflow  is lost. it has nothing to do with network or modem since transmission is working fine, browsers can't be blamed as i have tried 4(basically 3) different browsers, and **Apt-get** also have the problem